# Using sprites with dynamically generated SVG?

Tags: svg, sprite

I am trying to take some existing javascript which generates SVG elements and use a sprite sheet instead of individual pngs.

Right now this is the general format for generating the images, where "path" points to the file for a single image:

```
var hsOwnerDocument = $$(this).getDocument();
var element = hsOwnerDocument.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
element.id = id;
element.setAttributeNS(null, "x", left);
element.setAttributeNS(null, "y", top);
element.setAttributeNS(null, "width", width);
element.setAttributeNS(null, "height", height);
element.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", path);
```

I have no experience with SVG or sprites, but from my limited research there seem to be two approaches. Display the background-image to point to the sprite sheet and get the piece you need with CSS, or use a clip-path attribute on the image.  I'm not sure which is appropriate given my problem, but unfortunately neither seems to be working as I expect. The clip-path doesn't seem to be applying to the image element and if I use a background image instead it actually isn't displaying at all.

EDIT:
With the clip-path I just created an arbitrary rectangle smaller than my image and applied it to my image above to see if this would filter a region as I needed.

```
    var hsOwnerDocument = $$(this).getDocument();
    var element = hsOwnerDocument.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "clip-path");
    element.id = "testClip";
    element.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "testClip");
    var rect = hsOwnerDocument.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 4);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 4);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", 20);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", 20);
    element.appendChild(rect);
```

I applied the clip-path as an attribute by adding another line to the earlier code:

```
element.setAttributeNS(null,"style", "clip-path:url(#testClip)");
```

The clip-path element and child rectangle are both present in the resulting markup, and I see the attribute on my image element... but the full image still displays.

Comment: @RobertLongson added additional details, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect.

```
var element = hsOwnerDocument.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                                              "clip-path");
```

You need to create a clipPath element.

```
var element = hsOwnerDocument.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                                              "clipPath");
```

The property is clip-path, the element is [clipPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath).

Comment: Blargh, you are correct. That was a sloppy mistake. Unfortunately I misunderstood how this attribute worked... it is applied to the screen coordinates instead of the source image coordinates. This makes for some very complex position calculations and doesn't seem useful for sprites (unless I am missing something else).
Is this a case where I would want to use the background-image method instead?

Comment: Maybe you need to work in [objectBoundingBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#ClipPathElementClipPathUnitsAttribute) units instead then?

Comment: Haha, well the behavior is certainly different! Sadly not what I expect. With that property set I now see the entire image render if my position coordinates of the clipping rectangle are zero (or negative up to the dimensions). Otherwise I see nothing.

Comment: Your co-ordinates likely need to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yep, that will do it.  Definitely non-ideal from a maintenance perspective, but this can probably be made to work. Given how common a need I'd expect this to be, I'm surprised more direct support hasn't been added for working with sprites.